# Is there a keyboard shortcut for the R internal pipe operator |>?

Tags: r, pipe, rstudio, operator-keyword

For the pipe operator, %>%, I can set a shortcut. Can I also set a shortcut for |> as well?

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, Phil! I didn't find that duplicate question. I should have looked at the global options of RStudio more carefully.